# No error message launching applet through webstart when server not stared

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start

This is the opposite of the usual problems posted. I **don't** get an error message when I want one!

I have an applet client and a servlet server running in a Tomcat server. All is well. Except if you forget to start Tomcat and click on the Web Start desktop shortcut you get the Java 7 ... splash. And then the java console. And then nothing. No error; no client.

If I quickly turn the trace onto level 5 then it is reporting a `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect` but an end user would see nothing.

This is presumably because the single jar file can't be downloaded, but hey isn't Web Start supposed to cache the jar file? Or does the fact that the client is an applet not an application mean that it can't be offline? If you look at the trace below, it is saying my jar file has expired. This is untrue. I cleared all the Web Start cache stuff, ran it with the server working to create the desktop shortcut and then tried immediately again with the server unstarted.

If the connection is lost once the application is running, then our code detects that and reports to the user, so is it a bug that Java Web Start is not reporting a communication issue with the server where the jnlp file and server are located?

Or am I missing something?

Any help much appreciated.

trace is:

```
Trace level set to 5: all ... completed.java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequestEX(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.checkUpdateAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.isUpdateAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.model.ResourceProvider.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory._buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.viewer.JNLP2Viewer$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
temp: new XMLParser with source:
temp: <jnlp href="sent.jnlp">
     <information>
      <title>Sentences Explorer 4.0</title> 
      <vendor>Lazysoft Ltd.</vendor>
      <icon href="./resources/sentences.gif"/>
      <icon type="splash" href="./resources/Splash.gif"/>
      <description>Sentences Enterprise Edition V4.0.172.EE</description>
      <shortcut online="false">
        <desktop/>
      </shortcut>
      <offline-allowed/>
     </information>
     <resources>
       <java version="1.7.0+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" java-vm-args="-Xss1m"/>
      <jar href="Sentences.jar" main="true" download="eager"/>
     </resources>
   <offline-allowed/> 
   <applet-desc
      name="Sentences Explorer V4.0.172.EE"
      main-class="com.sentences.main.Sentences"
      width="610"
      height="330"> 
      <param name="ServletProtocol" value="http"/>
      <param name="ServletPort" value="8090"/>
      <param name="FixedProfile" value="no"/>
      <param name="EditOption" value="Schema"/>
      <param name="FontSize" value="Default"/>
      <param name="ImageURLBase" value="/ImagesForSentences"/>
   </applet-desc>
   <security>
      <all-permissions/>
   </security>
</jnlp>

temp: 

returning ROOT as follows:

<jnlp href="sent.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>Sentences Explorer 4.0</title>
    <vendor>Lazysoft Ltd.</vendor>
    <icon href="./resources/sentences.gif"/>
    <icon type="splash" href="./resources/Splash.gif"/>
    <description>Sentences Enterprise Edition V4.0.172.EE</description>
    <shortcut online="false">
      <desktop/>
    </shortcut>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <java version="1.7.0+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" java-vm-args="-Xss1m"/>
    <jar href="Sentences.jar" main="true" download="eager"/>
  </resources>
  <offline-allowed/>
  <applet-desc name="Sentences Explorer V4.0.172.EE" main-class="com.sentences.main.Sentences" width="610" height="330">
    <param name="ServletProtocol" value="http"/>
    <param name="ServletPort" value="8090"/>
    <param name="FixedProfile" value="no"/>
    <param name="EditOption" value="Schema"/>
    <param name="FontSize" value="Default"/>
    <param name="ImageURLBase" value="/ImagesForSentences"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
</jnlp>
temp: returning LaunchDesc from XMLFormat.parse():

<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://LAZYWS04:8090/Sentences/" href="http://LAZYWS04:8090/Sentences/sent.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>Sentences Explorer 4.0</title>
    <vendor>Lazysoft Ltd.</vendor>
    <homepage href="null"/>
    <description>Sentences Enterprise Edition V4.0.172.EE</description>
    <icon href="http://LAZYWS04:8090/Sentences/resources/sentences.gif" kind="default"/>
    <icon href="http://LAZYWS04:8090/Sentences/resources/Splash.gif" kind="default"/>
    <shortcut online="false" install="false">
      <desktop/>
    </shortcut>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <update check="timeout" policy="always"/>
  <resources>
    <java java-vm-args="-Xss1m" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.7.0+"/>
    <jar href="http://LAZYWS04:8090/Sentences/Sentences.jar" download="eager" main="true"/>
  </resources>
  <applet-desc name="Sentences Explorer V4.0.172.EE" main-class="com.sentences.main.Sentences" documentbase="http://LAZYWS04:8090/Sentences/" width="610" height="330">
    <param name="EditOption" value="Schema"/>
    <param name="ServletProtocol" value="http"/>
    <param name="ServletPort" value="8090"/>
    <param name="FixedProfile" value="no"/>
    <param name="FontSize" value="Default"/>
    <param name="ImageURLBase" value="/ImagesForSentences"/>
  </applet-desc>
</jnlp>
preloader: Added pending event 1: ConfigEvent[type=SetVisible, value=true]
cache: JNLPPreverifyClassLoader.initialize: FAILED: http://LAZYWS04:8090/Sentences/Sentences.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL2 called for http://LAZYWS04:8090/Sentences/Sentences.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.drainPendingURLs addURL called for http://LAZYWS04:8090/Sentences/Sentences.jar
preloader: Added pending event 2: ConfigEvent[type=AppInfo, value=Appinfo:
type = 2
title = Sentences Explorer 4.0
vendor = Lazysoft Ltd.
from = http://LAZYWS04:8090/Sentences/Sentences.jarjnlp
security = 2
lapURL = http://LAZYWS04:8090/Sentences/sent.jnlp
]
preloader: Added pending event 3: InitEvent[type=App]
network: LaunchDownload: concurrent downloads from LD: 4
network: Total size to download: -1
security: Security check for progress jars: allSigned=true
preloader: Using preloader class: null com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter@8c3770
preloader: Using default preloader
preloader: Requested to use preloader class: null
preloader: Delivering: ConfigEvent[type=SetVisible, value=true]
preloader: Delivering: ConfigEvent[type=AppInfo, value=Appinfo:
type = 2
title = Sentences Explorer 4.0
vendor = Lazysoft Ltd.
from = http://LAZYWS04:8090/Sentences/Sentences.jarjnlp
security = 2
lapURL = http://LAZYWS04:8090/Sentences/sent.jnlp
]
preloader: Delivering: InitEvent[type=App]
preloader: Skipped all (0) download events prior to null
preloader: Preloader jars loaded. Error state=null
preloader: Start progressCheck thread
security: Blacklist revocation check is enabled
security: blacklist: created: NEED_LOAD, lastModified: 1382085215578
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1384520450937 (we have 1382085215578)
security: Trusted libraries list check is enabled
security: Certificate revocation enabled. Disable security validation optimizations.
security: Reset cached validation for http://LAZYWS04:8090/Sentences/Sentences.jar.
network: Cache entry found [url: http://LAZYWS04:8090/Sentences/Sentences.jar, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://LAZYWS04:8090/Sentences/Sentences.jar
cache: Resource http://LAZYWS04:8090/Sentences/Sentences.jar has expired.
network: Connecting http://LAZYWS04:8090/Sentences/Sentences.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting socket://LAZYWS04:8090 with proxy=DIRECT
preloader: Delivering: DownloadErrorEvent[url=http://LAZYWS04:8090/Sentences/Sentences.jar version=null label=Unable to load resource cause=Connection refused: connect
preloader: Delivering: ErrorEvent[url=http://LAZYWS04:8090/Sentences/sent.jnlp label=Connection refused: connect cause=Connection refused: connect
basic: exception: Connection refused: connect.
ExitException[ 3]java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.downloadResources(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.loadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
preloader: Delivering: ErrorEvent[url=null label=Connection refused: connect cause=Connection refused: connect
preloader: Preloader shutdown after ErrorEvent
preloader: Stop progressCheck thread
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever my clients launch their JWS apps and they receive no error messages or splash screen or anything, I always tell them to upgrade their version of Java and that has always fixed it.

I suggest checking java.com for the latest Java version.

Comment: I have reproduced this with several versions of Java, including the latest 7u45 at time of writing. I've also tried with 64-bit and 32-bit. As a developer, I usually try these things before posting but thanks for the suggestion. And yes - I've tried turning if off and back on again.